# What does WINEPREFIX do?

Tags: wine

*OS: Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 64-bit.*

I will first tell you how I installed Wine, which I don't need explanation for.

I removed old packages of the same program:

```
sudo apt-get purge wine-devel-amd64 wine-devel
```

Following the [official statement](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu), which I changed a little to my image:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

---

Now, I thought I might install Lightshot [the official way](https://app.prntscr.com/en/wine-lightshot.html):

```
wine ./setup-lightshot.exe
```

But it was complaining that I am using *wrong version of Windows*.

The installer is probably 32-bit. And `winetricks` told me:

> ```
> You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
> ```

I don't know what `WINEPREFIX` is, but I managed to create a 32-bit one as follows:

```
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/home/vlastimil/.lightshot winecfg
```

Which I configured for compatibility with Windows 10.

I then installed Lightshot as follows:

```
WINEPREFIX=/home/vlastimil/.lightshot wine start /unix /home/vlastimil/setup-lightshot.exe
```

---

Could anyone elaborate on what `WINEPREFIX` is, and why I can't just use:

```
wine ./whatever.exe
```

I would be grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wine supports multiple “Windows installations” side-by-side; these are what “Wine prefixes” refer to. Its default prefix is `~/.wine`, but any other prefix can be specified with the `WINEPREFIX` variable.

A prefix contains a complete Wine environment, with its settings and its installed software. Settings go in the various registries (`user.reg` etc.), installed software goes in a drive inside a prefix (typically `drive_c`). With multiple prefixes, you can maintain multiple environments, each with its own software — ensuring that settings are kept isolated, and one piece of software can’t interfere with another. (This also means that when a setup is irretrievably messed up, there’s less to reinstall!)

A prefix can support 32-bit programs, 64-bit programs, or both. By default, both are supported, assuming Wine64 and Wine32 are available. You’ve ended up with a 64-bit-only `~/.wine`; presumably when it was created, only Wine64 was available. `WINEARCH` can be used to determine the architecture of a newly-created prefix (it doesn’t need to be specified after the prefix has been created). There are some issues with combined prefixes which prevent many 32-bit programs from working correctly there, so [for the time being](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_do_I_create_a_32_bit_wineprefix_on_a_64_bit_system.3F) it’s better to use a 32-bit prefix for them.

If you don’t have anything you particularly care about in `~/.wine`, you can delete it and start again, to avoid having to set `WINEPREFIX`. Note that desktop entries created when Windows software is installed do set the appropriate variables, so you don’t have to worry about them after the initial setup if you only use the desktop entries.

The [Wine FAQ](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Wineprefixes) has a number of relevant answers.