# Should we use machine-wide Wine prefixes?

Tags: windows, wine

I recently [learned about `WINEPREFIX`es](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408865/55900), and it seems like its root folder usually ends up in the current user's home folder.

Ideally, I'd like the Windows software to be available to all users, so does each user need to set up separate Wine configurations or is there a way for me to use a "shared" Wine prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wine usually *does not* run if `WINEPREFIX` isn't owned by the user. That pretty much eliminates the option of a shared prefix. You can keep prefixes wherever you want, but each user will likely need their own copy of each prefix.

This is covered by [the Wine FAQ](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Can_I_install_applications_to_be_shared_by_multiple_users.3F):

> #### 7.2 Can I install applications to be shared by multiple users?
>
> Wine does not currently allow sharing its configuration ("prefixes")
>   between users, due to the risk of registry corruption from running
>   multiple wineservers simultaneously [bug #11112](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11112). At present,
>   applications must be installed separately for each user.
>
> However, you can copy Wine prefixes; you can install everything to one
>   prefix, then make a copy of it in each user's home directory. This
>   saves running installers repeatedly.